# How to fix 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to share a website I've done using GitHub pages, but I'm having troubles loading the JSON files.

This is for a friends game server website, using HTML 5, JavaScript and JSON, I've tried running it from localhost and it worked perferctly fine.
The issue actually is a `SyntaxError : Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` and when I try to look for the JSON file in chrome debugger I can't see my JSON files to check where the probleme could be coming from.

The JSON file :

```
{
    "header_menu_games": "Games",
    "header_menu_home": "Home",
    "header_menu_rules": "Rules",
    "header_menu_support": "Support",
    "header_serverip_text": "Server ip:",
    "header_serverip_copy_btn": "Copy"
}
```

The JavaScript code I use to translate :

```
if (isLanguageAvailable) {
    var myRequest = new Request(`../../src/lang/${userLang}.json`);
    console.info(`User language (${userLang}) is available`);
} else {
    var myRequest = new Request("../../src/lang/en.json");
    console.info(`The user language (${userLang}) is unfortunately not available`);
}
console.log(myRequest);

fetch(myRequest)
    .then(resp => {
        resp.json()
            .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("lang-header_serverip_text").innerHTML = data.header_serverip_text;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Console error:

[image: console_error]

JavaSript catch error:

[image: js_catch_error]

The full code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/Vianpyro/Aycraft).

Comment: You are getting 404 error. Its not a json.

Comment: i think if you fix your 404 which comes from a not found json file the syntax error will also disappear

Comment: you have to check for `resp.ok`

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to fix this 404 from a not found json file ; even if I change the path in the request, the file's not found

Comment: this is because github.io does not return that json file on the given path

Comment: @DanielA.White I've added a resp.ok ; I works perfectly fine from localhost, but returns false from GitHub pages

Comment: @messerbill I don't know why GitHub doesn't return the json file on the given path ; I use almost the same path for all my sources and it works...

Comment: @Vianpyro as you told Daniel and as u can see in the answer below, the given URL is the problem :) if the answer solves your problem please mark it using the green hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're receiving a 404 error because you're pointing your link at the repository location instead of the actual content. You were linking to a nonexistent link: https://vianpyro.github.io/src/lang/en.json

You can do this one of two ways:

1. Link to the raw version of the file from the repository
2. Point at the correct location from your friend's domain

---

### 1. Linking to the Raw Version

In github, click on `Raw` and it should open a page containing the actual JSON.

[image: Screenshot of Github]

You'll see that the actual link to the content is:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vianpyro/Aycraft/master/src/lang/en.json

---

### 2. Linking to the hosted location

Part of your original problem was that you weren't pointing at the right path. Your friend's site is hosted at https://vianpyro.github.io/Aycraft and not https://vianpyro.github.io/.

This means that the base url of the site is https://vianpyro.github.io/Aycraft and everything in the path has to follow that. You have to include the `/Aycraft` after the domain name since that is the baseurl of the site.

The correct url would be:
https://vianpyro.github.io/Aycraft/src/lang/en.json

Comment: Glad I could help! I updated my response for clarity for any others taking a look as well.